# Date format for 2016-10-20T13:01:47.317

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is what I am trying for getting date from the string **2016-10-20T13:01:47.317** but getting `nil`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateString = [dateString substringToIndex:dateString.length - 3];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
```

Also tried with **yyyy** but still getting nil.
I was not able to understand **.317** so I eliminated that from the string. What shall be the date format for this ?

Comment: (That's [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The .317 is simply fractions of a second.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it  .317 means milliseconds use `SSS`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS"]; // or omit the timezone use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: So this is the one : yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS

Comment: @Nitish - correct , else use your local timezone for omit the `T`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use date format as

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: what is the use of z in here

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this DateFormatter `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` in your code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
```

Here date is not nil

Comment: if you use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` then you can't omit the dateString.length - 3]

Comment: That is for the string ` 2016-10-20T13:01:47.317`

Comment: Ok i get it, he is removing last three character .

Comment: if you are remove the 3 chars then use yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

Try this for remove millisecond :

```
NSString *dateString = @"your string";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS";
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

Comment: where is timezone`T`

Comment: sorry i for got to change it . try now my updated answer

Comment: what the use of second dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"; in here

Comment: it is for removing your last 3 digit